VS Code Drag and Drop Database to .ipynb Not working?
Currently test driving the new Oracle SQL Developer extension for VS code and was referencing this Youtube Video: https://youtu.be/e-yqkI0t6dQ?t=2784
Noticed the presenter had a database open and simply dragged from the left hand side menu bar the title of the database into an open .ipynb code cell and the code was auto generated and only needed minor editing for the connection details.
Thought this was a cool feature, tried to give it a try and when I did this nothing happened in my code window?
Not sure if theres a setting in VS code that I need to enable? Any one else try this extension out?

This was a preview of things we're working on in the extension, so that hasn't been put into the product, YET.
But it's coming later this year!
